# When product X only allow that product in the cart and show specific payment method

Tags: magento-1.9, payment-methods

We have some process issues with our store, just throwing it out here to see if anybody has a bright idea.

We have a product that is under development but we want people to reserve the product so we know roughly how much we need to create. Currently what we have is a payment method called "Reservation". This payment method allows you to create the order without paying. Problem we have is that sometimes people choose Reservation for other products and we need to cancel them etc.

I tried a payment method restriction module but that doesn't work in our show due to our payment provider module. And we always have the problem "What if they put a normal product in the cart and a reservation product"

So that's why I added this subject, When product X only allow that product in the cart and show specific payment method

any thoughts?

Answer (score 7):

There are two possible ways I can think of achieving this in Magento:

1. In the past I have done something similar by completely "rebranding" the wishlist functionality in Magento with different. It gave customers the ability to reserve and share their reservation of a product in Magento and the only thing that gave away that we were using the wishlist functionality was the URL's. That being said, this may not work for you if you're already implementing the wishlist feature in your store.
2. Create a new Magento "Store Group" in Magento just for upcoming products and the only payment method is Reservation. They will not share carts, nor root catalogues, however you can configure them to share their customers, so that your existing customers will be able to have an account on that "upcoming products" store automatically.

Comment: I think option #2 might work out to be effective and relatively easy.

Answer (score 3):

Did a quick extension for this, see: https://github.com/Genmato/ReserveOnly

The extension adds a new Product Attribute (`reserved_product_only` or Tab `Reserve Product` => `Reservable Product` on product edit page). When set to 'Yes', it is not possible to checkout when there are normal products and reservable products in the cart. And message is displayed of the error (can be set in System=>Configuration=>Catalog=>Reserved Only Products=>Message).

It is also possible to specify the Payment method to use for Reservable products, when there are only reservable products in the cart then only this payment method is selectable, otherwise this payment method is hidden from the payment methods listed.

It was just a quick setup and not that well tested, but maybe it is a good base to start with.